# how to change background-position with jquery.css()

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following css description with 2 different sprite images that will be displayed left and right :
    #username { background-position: 2px 2px, 500px 6px !important;}

and now I want to use jQuery to change the position of right sprite image e.g. change to 300px 6px.

```
$("#username").css({background-position: 2px 2px, 300px 6px !important});
```

this one is not working.

I want to know how to write it.
Who can help me?

Any help would be great.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can't set `!important` with jQuery, is that a requirement ?

Comment: `$('#username').prop('style', 'background-position: 2px 2px, 300px 6px !important')`

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten the quotes around `'2px 2px, 300px 6px !important'`.

Comment: not working, but thanks.

Comment: no, !improtant is not requirement

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to wrap `value` in `quotes` and it is `backgroundPosition` as object

```
$("#username").css({backgroundPosition: '2px 2px 300px 6px'});
                              ^          ^                ^
```

or

```
$("#username").css({'background-position': '2px 2px 300px 6px'});
```

Comment: I thought either `backgroundPosition` or `background-position` were valid..?

Comment: @JoshC - not as an object, but you can do : `$("#username").css('background-position', '2px 2px 300px 6px');`

Comment: Thanks you all, but I tried all what you proposed, still not working :(. I use jQuery 2.0.3.

Comment: @Ben can u make a fiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

In javascript objects you shouldn't use dashes. Instead, camelcase your properties like this:

```
$("#username").css({backgroundPosition: '2px 2px 300px 6px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#username").css('background-position', '2px 2px, 300px 6px !important');
```

or

```
$("#username").css('background-position', '2px 2px, 300px 6px');
```

Hope this helps.